# Writing to a VFP Database using the Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider in PHP

Tags: php, visual-foxpro

I am having trouble writing to a VFP database in php using visual fox pro OLE DB Provider (vfpoledb.dll). I have no problem accessing the data with select statements as described and answered in this question:

[Php, odbc & vfp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740869/php-odbc-vfp)

However when it comes to writing I am having trouble receving a

```
Cannot update the cursor ''tablename'', since it is read-only.
```

I thought the solution to this problem was to include *Mode="ReadWrite"* (have tried Share Exclusive also) in the Open command as described in the [msn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903388%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), as such :

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->Open('Provider="VFPOLEDB.1";Data Source="' . $filename . '";Mode="ReadWrite";');
```

However I still receive the same error when executing a statement such as:

```
$up = $conn->Execute("UPDATE tablename SET fieldname='Testing' WHERE fieldname = 'somevalue'");
```

Any ideas, is it even possible?
Anyone else love wrapping legacy systems?

Comment: What version of the driver is this ? I'm currently using the ODBC driver version 6.0 and I'm planning to use VFP OLE driver version 9.0

Comment: As far as I am aware it is v1.2 (I tired updating it by running the installer here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14839 )

Comment: OK, thanks. This is the one I was talking about. In you question you state it's vfpodbc.dll, but VfpOleDB.dll is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this table part of a VFP database? Have you checked the file properties of the .DBF or the .DBC to see if they are read-only? This error typically means that the DBF or index(CDX or IDX) are marked as read-only.

Or, you might have performed a SELECT * FROM TABLE INTO CURSOR MyCURSOR which would make the cursor MyCURSOR read-only. In this case, you would want to add the READWRITE clause to the SELECT statement.

Comment: The table is part of a VFP database, I had checked the table dbf file already to see if it was read only (which it wasn't). I have just checked the databases dbc file to see if that was read only (which it was). I changed that but i'm still getting that error.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second point. I am not making any select statements into a cursor. Can you add READWRITE into *update* statements and if so what is the format?

Comment: There are other files associated with a DBC(DCT, DCX) and DBF(CDX, IDX, FTP). Ensure that these are not marked as read-only. Also, could the directory be read-only? Are you on a network? As for the READWRITE, that only applies when performing a SELECT statement. Your UPDATE looks correct.

Comment: Sorted it, classic file permission fail by the process accessing the data, my bad, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from other issues you are encountering, but my answer on the previously noted post made specific reference to the connection string.  Since you are not showing the value of the file name variable value, and going by the name OF that variable, I am assuming it is a full name of actual table you want to update.  If so, this is incorrect.

When doing a connection for VFP, you want to connect to the actual PATH that the data tables are located, not the actual table name itself.  Once connected, you can query ANY table within that PATH (and even sub-folders too if you so wanted to).

Make sure your connection is pointing to the PATH and not the actual table.dbf reference.

Comment: First thanks for you original post it was very helpful, however the connection string is not the problem. Your post made this very clear not to use the table name itself and my code does not (I am aware you can't see this from my post). I have sorted it now, classic file permission fail.

Comment: I was wondering as a follow up to this if you knew how to prepare or safe statments prior to execution as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645426/avoiding-injection-attacks-when-using-visual-foxpro-ole-db-provider-in-php

Comment: @hygap, sorry, but not experienced in php, I can't adequately answer... however, just doing concatenation of strings to build a query is always dangerous when the values can be provided by outside sources (mostly web-based), and should be PARAMETERIZED in the OleDB call... but again, I am not familiar with how php deals with parameterizing content of the query.