# How can I connect to these database(DBF, FPT) sources?

Tags: dbf

A software uses DBF and FPT files to manage its data. I am not familiar with these kinds databases or data storage. I was able to retrieve data using some PHP classes. But I need help to connect to this database in better ways so that I can export data efficiently and automatically.

Can these files be treated like database so that I can connect, select and filter data using other programming languages? Is it possible that these data sources are encrypted and protected by the software that uses them(I mean that then I wont be able to connect to them)?

Can I connect to these databases or data using .NET or can I run SQLs somehow so that I can export data quickly? Because when I read those files using PHP, I had to read the entire files which is taking a lot time. But the software which is using the files as data source can export data quickly from the frontend of the software. I need some guide to get started working with these data sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the .dbf and .fpt are associated with VFP (Visual FoxPro).  As you mentioned PHP (vs C#), I did a quick search on "vfp php" and had a bunch of hits for you to run with.  However, the first I think would give a good jump start is

[this one showing multiple ways to query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740869/php-odbc-vfp)

No matter which method you find / like, be sure to keep queries clean, parameterized and help prevent SQL-injection.

Since you have opted to go with VB.Net (instead of PHP per the question), I am more familiar with C#.net but would be similarly applied.

```
string sqlStatement = "select * from someTable where someKey = ?";
OleDbCommand oCmd = new OleDbCommand( sqlStatement );
oCmd.Parameters.Add( "someParmKey", someIntegerValueForExample );
```

the "?someParmKey" in the SQL statement.  the "?" represents a PLACE-HOLDER in your query, and the .Parametres.Add() must be in the same order as your query has them laid-out.  So if you have a query with 3 "?" place-holders, make sure you do .Parameters.Add() in the same order as the context of the parameters.

HTH

Comment: thanks, i was searching on google as "php dbf". I tried few classes from two sources, however the scripts were not able to read all columns. finally, i was able to come up with VB.NET solution.

Comment: @Robi, I could have offered many C#.net examples using VFP, but you had mentioned PHP.  But with whatever your strength is (VB vs C#), there are plenty of examples, but be sure to PARAMETERIZE your queries to prevent sql-injection.

Comment: i have also posted an answer how i was able to resolve the issue. does sql injection also happen in VB, c# and c++? i was building few other VB apps for my school which can create CRUD apps easily. are they sql-injection protected by default?

Comment: @Robi, revised answer for clarification on SQL parameterization against VFP provider.

Comment: that's great which looks like php pdo parametrization, i dont have any privilege to upvote :)

Comment: @Robi, by upchecking as a solution is also part of an acceptance too.. this way others know a solution was made and others don't have to keep trying to offer answers on an already solved question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the dbf file with .NET using ODBC:

```
private void ConnectToDBF()
{            
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection oConn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
    oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=D:\databases\;Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
    oConn.Open();
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();

    // Read the table
    oCmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM C:\dbf\test.dbf";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());

    oConn.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: thanks, finally i came up with a VB solution. luckily i was taking a VB class this semester.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to others who already answered the question. Beside these helpful answers, I found the following definition very useful which has been taken from [this source(click here)](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/connect-foxpro-data-dbf-vbulletin-net-t2317271.html) and then I was able to implement a VB solution quickly.

> "FoxPro tables come in 3 parts: the DBF is the main table, the FPT
>   (optional) is the contents of Memo fields, and the CDX (also optional)
>   is the associated index file. All three of these generally named the
>   same excepting the extension and if your table has Memo fields and
>   indexes then the FPT and CDX must be present.
>
> There are two ways Fox tables are organized. First, there are "free"
>   tables. With free tables a DBC file is not present and the connection
>   string should reference only the directory where the files are found,
>   as you have done below.
>
> Second, Fox tables can be associated with a "Database Container" (DBC,
>   DCT memo, and DCX index files) which contains metadata about the
>   tables and other features such as stored procedures and triggers. If a
>   DBC is present the path in your connection string should be something
>   like "C:\ESS2001\DATA\Whatever.dbc"."

My final working code:

```
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\\data source;User ID=ADMIN"

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim com As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\\folder location of database;User ID=test"
    con.Open()

    Dim dBaseCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory", con)
    Dim dBaseDataReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dBaseCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)

    Dim partnumber As String
    Dim qty As String
    Dim unitcost As String
    Dim description As String
    Dim mfgr As String

    While dBaseDataReader.Read
        partnumber = dBaseDataReader("ITEMNUMBER")
        mfgr = dBaseDataReader("MFGR")
        qty = dBaseDataReader("QTY")
        unitcost = dBaseDataReader("UNITCOST")
        description = dBaseDataReader("DESCRIPTION")

        Out.WriteLine("""" & partnumber & """,""" & unitcost & """,""" & qty & """,""" & description & """,""" & mfgr & """")
    End While

    status.Text = "Complete"
    Me.Close()
```